# Does FFMPEG rewrite HLS m3u8 playlist files from scratch every segment when -hls_playlist_type = event?

Tags: ffmpeg

`hls_playlist_type event` means the playlist file is supposed to be appended with each new segment reference and segments are never removed.

And yet I've always noticed in the ffmpeg log with each update:

`[hls @ 000001c7870a4440] Opening '720p.m3u8.tmp' for writing`

Which looks like it's not doing a simple append but rewriting the entire lot.
Every other playlist type this makes sense for but, for this it doesn't.

I'm using ffmpeg to create very (very) long running playlists containing potentially tens of thousands of segments, and if I'm correct in my assumption then it's going to be doing a lot of unnecessary writing and I'll need to find an alternative.